# Linking to and using specific html markup on another page

Tags: html

I am writing the markup for a newspaper-type website, in which articles will be continually removed and replaced by new articles on the Home Page. All the articles on the Home Page will be links to another page where the article can be read. These same article links will also be placed on the other html pages.

I would like to keep all of the html markup for these article links in a single "library" html page. Then, when I want to refer to them on the index page and elsewhere, I need only reference the "library" items by some identifying code; as simple as a numerical id. Thus, when I populate the library.html page with "article01" (for example), wherever "article01" is noted on the other pages, the html markup for that article will be used on the other pages automatically; eliminating the process of deleting the previous markup and adding the lengthy markup to each page manually.

Is there such a html markup that will perform this action?

Honestly, I have no idea on how to solve this. It seems it must be some form of link, but how do you capture and use the html markup you're targeting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this will help in your case but you may try out [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) which would allow you to generate HTML based on markup.

If that is not what you're looking for, I personally believe there is no html-only solution. You may delve into PHP, Javascript or use a CMS like Wordpress.

Alternatively, you can create each HTML file manually (but Jekyll speeds this process up by a significant amount.)